# Rails refactor view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm having following view

```html-erb
<div class='post-helpers'>
  <% if current_user.id == @post.user_id %>
    <%= button_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), class: 'btn', tabindex: 1 %>
    <%= button_to 'Delete', @post, class: 'btn', tabindex: 2, method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

`current_user.id == @something.user_id` is being used in a lot of places so I'm trying to move it out in `application_helper`.
How can this be done?

PS: This helper needs to be reusable and should not depend only on `@post`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def owner?(object)
  current_user && current_user.id == object.user_id
end
```

Too you can make it more general and allow check rules for `current_user` but for any user:

```
def owner?(object, user = nil)
  user ||= current_user
  user && user.id == object.user_id
end
```

Usage

```
<div class='post-helpers'>
  <% if owner?(@post) %>
    <%= button_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), class: 'btn', tabindex: 1 %>
    <%= button_to 'Delete', @post, class: 'btn', tabindex: 2, method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help)
According to posts, I have read, if I need to use any kind of Ruby in the view, it should be for things like:

1.  iterating through a list of objects
2. calling an attribute on a Model object to show it’s value
3. Any kind of forms
4. Rendering views

So, my question is: Is there a way to remove all logic evenif statements out of view?

Comment: Really, no. But you can use partials, helpers or gems like drapper, cell to make your code dry and void nested `if`